# Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group when OpenCV is added to the library; possible fix?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

**Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group** , found many existing question with same tag, however none did fix my issue.

I am trying to include OpenCV with my project in order to track hand position. And so far everything works fine, however when I build the project. It gives the error : `Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group` .

From the log here is what I obtained :

> Ld /Users/shaheenakader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handSeg-fiojpqxgqvrsbxadwvnbdsljpycy/Build/Products/Debug/handSeg normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/shaheenakader/Documents/tracking
>       export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -L/Users/shaheenakader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handSeg-fiojpqxgqvrsbxadwvnbdsljpycy/Build/Products/Debug -L/usr/local/lib -F/Users/shaheenakader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handSeg-fiojpqxgqvrsbxadwvnbdsljpycy/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/shaheenakader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handSeg-fiojpqxgqvrsbxadwvnbdsljpycy/Build/Intermediates/handSeg.build/Debug/handSeg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/handSeg.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/shaheenakader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handSeg-fiojpqxgqvrsbxadwvnbdsljpycy/Build/Intermediates/handSeg.build/Debug/handSeg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/handSeg_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_core.2.4.10 -lopencv_objdetect.2.4.10 -lopencv_highgui.2.4.10 -lopencv_imgproc.2.4.10 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/shaheenakader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handSeg-fiojpqxgqvrsbxadwvnbdsljpycy/Build/Intermediates/handSeg.build/Debug/handSeg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/handSeg_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/shaheenakader/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/handSeg-fiojpqxgqvrsbxadwvnbdsljpycy/Build/Products/Debug/handSeg

Also,

> ld: library not found for -lopencv_imgcodecs
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Previously**

I manually built the `OpenCV` library using `Cmake` .

And inside my Xcode project, I set header search path to : `/usr/local/include`

and library search path to : `/usr/local/lib` .

Also, set other linker flags to : `-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab`

What could possibly be causing this issue, and how to resolve this issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And the library `opencv_imgcodecs` *is* in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nope there isn't one !

Comment: If it's not in `/usr/local/lib`, you should change that to the path where the libraries are. A side note, you can use CMake GUI to generate an Xcode project that can be opened and compiled in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not enough just to link libraries in Xcode. You need to add the libraries into the projects. To do so, go to `/usr/local/libs` and drags them to the project explorer (the left panel of Xcode) and choose to create references on the pop up window. You can uncheck the option `copy if needed` on that window to avoid unnecessary clones of the libraries.

Comment: Thanks, did the same , however the error still persists :/ . Any guess?